# Different colors for each line in the graph

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data from a file. The file contains 13 columns, but i want just the first and the fourth column to plot. Also, there are more than one of the file, i want to plot them on the same diagram. I succeeded to show lines on the diagram. I added  my code for plotting arrays. The problem is that i want to have different colors for each file, but my code does the same for all. How can i correct it? 
Thank you.

```
# gen_len is an array, same for all files
# gen_number is an array contains information 
# of files 
colors="bgrcmyk"
index=0
for gen in gen_number:
    plt.plot(gen,gen_len,color=colors[index])
    index=index+1
plt.savefig('result.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: There is way too much code here, please reduce it to the minimal code which will demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more elegant solution for reading in your files would be to use numpy's genfromtxt, which can import just your desired columns, and also ignore lines starting with a certain character (the `comments='#'` keyword). I think this code does as you want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys 

colors="bgrcmyk"

for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
    gen,gen_len=np.genfromtxt(sys.argv[i],usecols=(0,3),unpack=True,comments='#')
    plt.plot(gen,gen_len,c=colors[i])

plt.savefig('result.png')
```

Comment: Thanks it worked as i wanted.Just one problem, in `for` loop i used `range(1,len(sys.argv))` to avoid to get name of my program file.

Comment: Graet, glad it worked. I've edited the answer to include that